# C# LINQ Arrange Multiple Columns Value and Resign to Specific Columns

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have tried this with Foreach loop, a new array and is working but I want to learn and see if there is a better way to do this with LINQ lambda.

I have a fruits table like this

```
public class fruits
{
   string id {get;set;}
   string fruit1 {get;set;}
   string fruit2 {get;set;}
   string fruit3 {get;set;}
}
```

Somehow not all fruit field in the table got filled for example:

```
id    fruit1    fruit2    fruit3
1     Apple               Kiwi
2               Lime
3                         Watermelon
4               Oranges   Grapes
```

Need output like:

```
id    fruit1    fruit2    fruit3
1     Apple     Kiwi          
2     Lime          
3     Watermelon                    
4     Oranges   Grapes
```

tried the following step to make this working

1. foreach loop through the list of fruits object
2. add fruit1 ,fruit2 ,fruit3 to a new array
3. create a for loop base on the array.length assign value like so object fruit  [i]

I would like to know if there a better way to do this with LINQ lambda.

thanks

Comment: What's the rule for assigning a fruit to a particular column ?

Comment: #aubury by a specific column I meant the f1, f2 ,f3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach with `Linq`

```
fruits[] output = input.Select(x => {
var items = new[] { x.fruit1, x.fruit2, x.fruit3 }.Where(y => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y));
                return  new fruits() {
                    id = x.id,
                    fruit1 = items.ElementAtOrDefault(0),
                    fruit2 = items.ElementAtOrDefault(1),
                    fruit3 = items.ElementAtOrDefault(2)
                };}).ToArray();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/OXYWpW

---

the imo better approach with loop

```
foreach (fruits item in fruitarray)
{
    var columns = new[] { item.fruit1, item.fruit2, item.fruit3 }.Where(y => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y));
    item.fruit1 = columns.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
    item.fruit2 = columns.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
    item.fruit3 = columns.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/RVhl9n

Answer (score 2):

So using [ternary conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) this would look like this, although using a loop would be more readable.

```
list = list.Select(x => new fruits
        {
            id = x.id,
            fruit1 = x.fruit1 ?? x.fruit2 ?? x.fruit3,
            fruit2 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.fruit1) ? (x.fruit2 ?? x.fruit3) : string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.fruit2) ? null : x.fruit3,
            fruit3 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.fruit1) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.fruit2) ? null : x.fruit3
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq-operations [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1), [Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1):

```
var projection = fruitses.Select(r=> 
    new fruits { 
        id = r.id, 
        fruit1 = new List<string>(){r.fruit1, r.fruit2, r.fruit3}   
            .FirstOrDefault(s=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)), 
        fruit2 = new List<string>(){r.fruit2, r.fruit3}
            .Skip(r.fruit1==null?1:0)
            .Skip(r.fruit2==null?1:0)
            .FirstOrDefault(s=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)), 
        fruit3 = new List<string>(){r.fruit3}
            .Skip(r.fruit1==null?1:0)
            .Skip(r.fruit2==null?1:0)
            .FirstOrDefault(s=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    });
```

[.NET Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T5DcXu)

Answer (score 1):

first i would go about making a list of those fruit so u can actually do something with them. preferably u would store them in a list to begin with;

add a property fruits that returns the fruits as a list.

```
public List<string> fruit
    {
        get { return new List<string> { this.fruit1, this.fruit2, this.fruit3 };}
        set {
            this.fruit1 = value.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
            this.fruit2 = value.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
            this.fruit3 = value.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
        }
    }
```

so taking a list of the Fruits object:

```
List<Fruits> fruitList = {...};
```

u can then remove all fruits where there is nothing, thus creating a list with no empty spots.

```
fruitList.ForEach(s => s.fruits =  s.fruits.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList());
```

However, this list can be shorter than the previous list as all empty strings get removed. So we must check if the value at the appropriate index still exists. We do this with *ElementAtOrDefault*, this return null if there is no value present at the index.

You must note however that this is not a sustainable way of keeping these objects as u will need to create more fruit properties for every increase in the number of fruit u want to store in a row. so it would be best to just store those fruit in a list to begin with and circumvent all these problems.